# Как предоставить пользователю список всех серверов, из лок бд?

Tags: android, xml

Есть приложение, с начальным экраном

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут три EditText с подсказками Server, E-mail, Password

При каждом новом подключении все три поля записываются в лок бд
Теперь мне нужно заменить эти EditText на ,что то вроде "предоставить пользователю список всех серверов, из лок бд" и чтоб обязательно осталась функция добавления нового сервера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте [выпадающее (Popup menu)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu) и последним элементом пускай будет "Добавить сервер" по нажатию на которое появится [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment) с EditText

Comment: Это то, что мне надо. Ещё раз спасибо!!!